# Can't build Unity Project with Facebook SDK, getting a 403 error?

Tags: facebook, maven, unity-game-engine, gradle, applovin

I've been trying for the last few days to build my project in Unity, but I keep receiving a Gradle error whenever I try. I have added the app ID from FB to the settings and messed around as much as I can, but can't find a solution.

Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':unityLibrary:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:[8.0, 9).
     Required by:
         project :unityLibrary
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://artifacts.applovin.com/android/com/facebook/android/facebook-applinks/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://artifacts.applovin.com/android/com/facebook/android/facebook-applinks/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://artifacts.applovin.com/android/com/facebook/android/facebook-applinks/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[8.0, 9).
     Required by:
         project :unityLibrary
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-core.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://artifacts.applovin.com/android/com/facebook/android/facebook-core/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://artifacts.applovin.com/android/com/facebook/android/facebook-core/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://artifacts.applovin.com/android/com/facebook/android/facebook-core/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-gamingservices:[8.0, 9).
     Required by:
         project :unityLibrary
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-gamingservices.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://artifacts.applovin.com/android/com/facebook/android/facebook-gamingservices/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://artifacts.applovin.com/android/com/facebook/android/facebook-gamingservices/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://artifacts.applovin.com/android/com/facebook/android/facebook-gamingservices/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[8.0, 9).
     Required by:
         project :unityLibrary
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-login.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://artifacts.applovin.com/android/com/facebook/android/facebook-login/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://artifacts.applovin.com/android/com/facebook/android/facebook-login/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://artifacts.applovin.com/android/com/facebook/android/facebook-login/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[8.0, 9).
     Required by:
         project :unityLibrary
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-share.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://artifacts.applovin.com/android/com/facebook/android/facebook-share/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://artifacts.applovin.com/android/com/facebook/android/facebook-share/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://artifacts.applovin.com/android/com/facebook/android/facebook-share/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 38s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. It may be related with the jcenter being discontinued. I tried to update the SDK, but it was still showing the same errors.

Update:
I fixed the issue by changing the target API from 33 to 32 and I did this change on my mainTemplate.gradle :

Before

```
([rootProject] + (rootProject.subprojects as List)).each { project ->
    project.repositories {
        ...
        mavenLocal()            
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}
```

After

```
([rootProject] + (rootProject.subprojects as List)).each { project ->
    project.repositories {
        ...
        mavenLocal()  
        google()          
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

**Move the google() up.**